# What is the timestamp and features in LSTM for time series data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to classify a ID by using hourly data per day.
I have a dataset which has following structure:

```
 ID |  t1  |  t2  |  t3  |  ...  |  t24 
  1 | v1,1 | v1,2 | v1,3 |  ...  | v1,24
  2 | v2,1 | v2,2 | v2,3 |  ...  | v2,24
  ...
```

where t stand for the timestamp from 12am to 11pm, and each ID has it hourly value in 24 hours.

I want to predict the ID by using the data sequence from t1 to t24, for example:

```
 v1,1 , v1,2 , v1,3 ,  ...  , v1,24  -> ID 1
```

Does the input data sequence should be `input_shape=(1, 24)` in `lstm`

```
  [v1, v2, v3, ..., v24] => 1
```

or `input_shape=(24, 1)` in `lstm`

```
[[v1],[v2],[v3], ..., [v24]] => 1
```

which one can match the assumption, using 24 hours data to classify the target?

Comment: I think that the dimension is (24, 1). 24 timesteps, 1 feature. See also https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/#:~:text=The%20LSTM%20input%20layer%20must,of%20time%20steps%20and%20features.

Comment: Thank you. I had read this article. Just confused that if I want to use data from 12am, 1am, 2am, ..., 11.pm, which are 24 hours data and include 1 value. Is it should be 24 timesteps, and 1 feature, so that the dimension is (24, 1)?

Comment: Are v1, v2, ..., v23, v24 numbers or vectors?